# MySQL - selecting usernames based on work submitted (two-variable)

Tags: mysql, count

Trying to figure out how I'd generate and order a list of usernames based on the amount of 'work' each does.

Consider a table, shares. Each share contains, among other things, a username and a difficulty (which is a number, a square of two). I'd like to assign credit to users (and order the list) as COUNT(username) multiplied by difficulty.

Here's my current query which does not factor in difficulty. I've not been able to do further group/join without causing an error.

```
SELECT username, COUNT(username) AS occurences
FROM shares
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY occurences DESC
```

A user may submit a share at multiple difficulties. The objective is to rank a user with the highest "share times difficulty" number first and lowest last.

Bonus points if it is possible to display the most popular difficulty per user. Thanks!

Comment: In your example I don't see where difficulty comes in. Is this in another table? Where is the data for the difficulty level/rating?

Comment: What do you mean by "COUNT(username) multiplied by difficulty." If count is on every share row, are you sure `SUM(difficulty)` is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your file has multiple records for a user, and each can have a different level of difficulty. You want to aggregate the difficulty and then divive by the number of records for that user, to compute an average difficulty.  If this assumption is correct, you could use:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(username) AS occurences, SUM(difficulty) AS difficulty
  , SUM(difficulty)/COUNT(username) As share_times_difficulty
FROM shares
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY share_times_difficulty DESC
```

See [this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1a61/5) for details.

If the assumptions are wrong, and you're looking for something different, please clarify.

Comment: The Fiddle is very helpful, thanks. To clarify I'm looking to measure the sum of (shares per difficulty for that share) per user.

Comment: So using the Fiddle's data, USR1 accomplishes 13 units of work (5*1)+(2*4); USR2 accomplishes 13 units of work (3*3)+(4*1); USR3 accomplishes 50 units of work (5*10). If there's a way to get the total number of units created - here, 76 - without a separate query, that would be very helpful as well!

Comment: Before getting to total, I don;t know if I'm still clear on what you want at the user level. I created another fiddle. See if this is what you need, or closer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/806d4/6

Comment: Closer - thank you. Though each row is a single share of some variable difficulty, belonging to one user, rather than containing a distinct shares_done number. Could we use COUNT(*) in its place somehow? The UNITS_OF_WORK is exactly the net result I'm looking for!

Comment: So, you're saying that shares_done is effectively = 1 ? In which canse, you really just want to sum up the difficulty by user?

Comment: I suggest you edit the Left hand side of that Fiddle, with a simple schema and simple insert of some representative data. (It automatically creates a new fiddle url which you can then add to your question)

Comment: Yes, each shares_done = 1. I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ee50/6) is it.

Comment: Okay, and this would be one way to get the total as well. (Just added a query of the total, and unioned it.) if you want the total line to come at the end, you can add some dummy field to both sub-queries and sort by that field too, in the ORDER BY.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ee50/7

Comment: Perfect, love the aggregate numbers!